# F#: Returning a Union Type From a Function

Tags: f#

Given the following working code.

```
type Square =
    { Foo : int }

type Circle =
    { Bar : int }

type Shape =
    | Square of Square
    | Circle of Circle

let Test x =
    match x with
    | Square { Foo = f } -> 
        Circle { Bar = f + 1 }
    | Circle { Bar = f } -> 
        Circle { Bar = f + 2 }


let a = Square { Foo = 1 }
let b = Test a
let c = Test b
```

The function Test has the expected return type (Shape -> Shape).
If I then change the definition of Test  slightly to...

```
let Test x =
    match x with
    | Square { Foo = f } -> 
        { Bar = f + 1 }
    | Circle { Bar = f } -> 
        { Bar = f + 2 }
```

The signature of the Test function changes to Shape -> Circle and the last line

```
let c = Test b
```

Now does not compile. Why does not the second definition of Test work?
Why does the signature of the Test function change?

Comment: because shape is not circle

Comment: elaborating in response to the edit `{Bar=f+1}` is a circle, not a shape.

Comment: Isn't it a circle in the working definition as well?

Comment: When you have `{Bar=f+1}` you are returning a record, this is an actual type, the fact that it is a possible value for a union case is irrelevant.

Comment: So what am I returning in the first version?

Comment: A shape - It might be clearer if you changed the definition to `type shape = |S of Square |C of Circle`

Comment: Oh...I see! Right. Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define the shape type like this:

```
type Shape =
    | Square of Square
    | Circle of Circle
```

it can be a little confusing because `Circle` appears twice.

As a result, in the first version:

```
Circle { Bar = f + 1 }
```

is actually a shape.  This is confusing because it almost looks like a constructor for the circle type, particularly from a C++ idiom where you have `new X()`.

As a result,

```
{ Bar = f + 1 }
```

is actually a Circle, which explains the error you are getting.